# Is TypeScript really a superset of JavaScript re: functions?

Tags: typescript

```
function foo(a: number, b: string): string {
    return a + b;
}
```

whether I put this in TypeScript playground or VS Code gets a 1068:
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Once I make that into a standard TS method signature (by removing the function keyword), everything is fine.

Yet the latest documentation on TypeScript:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Shows **function** is totally usable. Very strange.

Comment: Works fine here when tring that exact snippet on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: Yep: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: If you are inside a class then `function` is not allowed. But that hold true for es2015 classes as well..

Comment: Yes, standalone function works, but within a class definition not. [link]https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Yep, that is exactly how it works. Inside a class you don't use the function keyword and outside of it you need it.

Comment: @Alex.A That is also true for Javascript classes.. You can't have `function` inside a js class as defined in the es2015 standard

Comment: Interesting that the official spec: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#12-function-types doesn't mention this constraint, but TypeScript playground article on 'Functions' examples also never shows them inside a class either. I wonder if that's because a class becomes a function upon transpiling.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that shows the error you are getting:

```
class Foo {
  // ERROR unexpected token
  function foo(a: number, b: string): string {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

This is *invalid* TypeScript because, it is *invalid* JavaScript. e.g. the following is invalid:

[image]

Just another example of [TypeScript allows you to write JavaScript more safely](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/recap.html)